# Recorded video with front camera is showing blurry in android tablet

Tags: android, video, camera, video-recording

I am recording a video in android using media recorder. The video is recorded nicely in phone for both front and back camera but for tablet the video is recorded nicely for back camera but for front camera it is showing blurry. This is how my recorded video looks:
[image: this is what i get when i record from front cam in tablet]

my code for video recording is

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera c = null;
    try {

        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {

            //if you want to open front facing camera use this line   
            c = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);}

    //  c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //c = Camera.open(1); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    //mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    //mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
            .getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```